# How do I configure Tomcat timeout for CLOSE_WAIT connections

Tags: tomcat, timeout

How do I configure a Tomcat timeout for CLOSE_WAIT connections?

I have an high number of CLOSE_WAIT ports which results in a large number of unix open files.

(I've answered this question myself below btw. Just spreadin' the love :) )

Answer (score 0):

I Had a CLOSE_WAIT problem with an application running on tomcat, after days of suspecting these were being caused by a client and after much beating of head against screen trying to configure a timeout I eventually got to the bottom of it.

I read somewhere that the CLOSE_WAIT was a TCP condition that signified that the port was in a closed condition from the OS's point of view and was sitting waiting for the application to acknowledge. As such there is nothing from tomcat's POV to time out.

For me the issue ended up as a webservice hanging forever on a downstream component. When the client eventually timed out it left the port in CLOSE_WAIT state for evermore since the web app was sitting patently waiting to complete the request.

Indecently if it helps anyone jump straight to the solution for us it was our AMQ broker that had refused to accept any more messages since the disk space had breached a predefined limit. The pending enqueuing messages then stacked up holding the (webapp) client & the webapps's clients request.